# Creating new math environment using empheq

Tags: math-mode, environments, empheq

I defined a new environment called `boxew`. When I use the code

```
\begin{empheq}[box=\fbox]{align}
  \bar{\nabla}^{\mu} \bar{h}_{\mu\nu} & = 0 \\
  \bar{\nabla}^{\mu} \bar{h}_{\mu\nu} & = 0
\end{empheq}
```

I get boxed equations as I want. When I use the environment `boxeq` which I predefined:

```
 \newenvironment{boxeq}
    {\begin{empheq}[box=\fbox]{align} }
    {\end{empheq}}
```

it won't compile. See example below:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{empheq}

\newenvironment{boxeq}
{\begin{empheq}[box=\fbox]{align} }
{\end{empheq}}

\begin{document}

Multiline:

\begin{empheq}[box=\fbox]{align}
  \bar{\nabla}^{\mu} \bar{h}_{\mu\nu} & = 0 \\
  \bar{\nabla}^{\mu} \bar{h}_{\mu\nu} & = 0
\end{empheq}

Multiline \texttt{boxeq}:
\begin{boxeq}
\bar{\nabla}^{\mu} \bar{h}_{\mu\nu} & = 0 \\
\bar{\nabla}^{\mu} \bar{h}_{\mu\nu} & = 0
\end{boxeq}

\end{document}
```

There is probably a small syntax error but I can't find it. Can you please help?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here `empheq` relies on being able to explicitly see `\end{empheq}`. It is much easier to use modern tools to define `boxeq`. If your LaTeX format isn't after October 2020, remember to load `xparse`:

```
\NewDocumentEnvironment{boxeq}{b}{}{
  \begin{empheq}[box=\fbox]{align}
    #1
  \end{empheq}
}
```

this special env will grab the contents of the env (the `b` specifier) and then we can pass it on to `empheq` via `#1`.